# Finding an element by AccessibilityId and index

Tags: xcode, xcuitest

I have multiple buttons with the same accessibilityID. I want to get the 3rd one.

Getting the first one is easy with

```
let severityItems = app.buttons["MyListItems"].firstMatch
```

But if I want the 3rd one and do it this way

```
let severityItems = app.buttons["MyListItems"].element(boundBy: 2)
```

I get an error: Value of type 'XCUIElement' has no member 'element'

Strange. I seems to get an array. If I po it in the debugger it shows me the elements correctly. How can I get the 3rd element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.buttons["MyListItems"]` returns an XCUIElementQuery, not an array of elements. If you look at [the documentation for that](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery) you'll see [a property called allElementsBoundByIndex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery/1500945-allelementsboundbyindex), which returns an array of elements.